# why Href attribute can't redirect to the respective ".js" file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

why my button is not redirecting to the respective .js file? Basically i am usiing Button with href tage where href="signup.js" and signup.js file is present in my project...... Can we use href tag to link a ".js" file properly and redirect properly... Button has been imported from react-bootstrap so what changes should be madeso user click on Button and go to signup.js file?

```
 import React from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import Typography from '../components/Typography';
    import ProductHeroLayout from './ProductHeroLayout';
    
    const backgroundImage =
      'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/female-boss-online-conference-meeting-woman-crossed-hands-office-desk-front-laptop-student-teaches-exam-139215819.jpg';
    
    const styles = (theme) => ({
      background: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
        backgroundColor: '#7fc7d9', // Average color of the background image.
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
      },
      button: {
        minWidth: 200,
      },
      h5: {
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(4),
        marginTop: theme.spacing(4),
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
          marginTop: theme.spacing(10),
        },
      },
      more: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
      },
    });
    
    function ProductHero(props) {
      const { classes } = props;
    
      return (
        <ProductHeroLayout backgroundClassName={classes.background}>
          {/* Increase the network loading priority of the background image. */}
          <img style={{ display: 'none' }} src={backgroundImage} alt="increase priority" />
          <Typography color="inherit" align="center" variant="h2" marked="center">
            Upgrade your knowledge
          </Typography>
          <Typography color="inherit" align="center" variant="h5" className={classes.h5}>
            Test Your Skills.
          </Typography>
          <Button
            color="secondary"
            variant="contained"
            size="large"
            href="SignUp.js"
          >
            User Registeration
          </Button>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="inherit" className={classes.more}>
            Be Digital
          </Typography>
        </ProductHeroLayout>
      );
    }
    
    ProductHero.propTypes = {
      classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };
    
    export default withStyles(styles)(ProductHero);
```

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically navigate between React components use [ReactRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic)

Comment: <Button
            color="secondary"
            variant="contained"
            size="large"
            href="SignUp.js"
          >
            User Registeration
          </Button>